# Can´t run an jnlp file. Shows message "Cannot run application"

Tags: java, web, netbeans, java-web-start, jnlp

so i'm recently starting to work with Java Web Start, everything was ok untill i tried to run my .jnlp file and it showed the message "Cannot run application" giving me only two options "Ok" & "Details". I selected details and this is what it showed:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:232)
at java.util.jar.JarOutputStream.putNextEntry(JarOutputStream.java:109)
at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpDownloadHelper.decompressWrite(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpDownloadHelper.download(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToTempFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToCache(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried searching a solution for this problem, but i didnt have any luck. Thanks! 
Apologies for my english!

Content of the JNLP:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="file:/C:/Users/JuanCarlos/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ouma.administracfdi.Reader/dist/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>ouma.administracfdi.Reader</title>
    <vendor>JuanCarlos</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>ouma.administracfdi.Reader</description>
    <description kind="short">ouma.administracfdi.Reader</description>
<offline-allowed/>
</information>
<update check="background"/>
<resources>
    <j2se java-vm-args="-Xms2048m" version="1.8+"/>
    <jar href="ouma.administracfdi.Reader.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="lib/jxl.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/poi-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/poi-examples-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/poi-excelant-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-20150929.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="ouma.administracfdi.reader.CfdiReader">
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: What is a) the content of the JNLP. b) the listing of the jar content of all the jas maentioned in (a) (try `jar -tvf the.jar` from commend line)?

Comment: it looks as if there is more than one copy of `org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class` and it does not know how to handle that.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for responding Andrew I added the content of my .jnlp file. Thanks!

Comment: ..and what is the Jar file listing? I'm thinking the same thing as @StefanHegny - I need that listing to check.

Comment: I solved it! There was a security problem since this are not my own jars my computer was blocking them from executing, i decided to run the program in the owners laptop and it worked, really strange. Thanks!!